# Do I have to implement the UserInterface for Users in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a webpage with symfony. Are there any advantages in implementing the `UserInterface` from `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User`?

It seems to me, that this interface would not fully represent my needs. For example do not need and want a username rather than just an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it as many components e.g. Security use it.

Your User can be extended or simplified. For username just do

```
public function getUsername() 
{
    return $this->getEmail();
}
```